# Security problems on Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, https

Since some weeks ago I've have been having problems in Firefox to load the latex symbols, it says the site has some insecure contents, I use Debian Linux distribution, but I'm having the same problem in Windows OS (so this problem has nothing to do with OS's)

Maybe the site has changed how it works, is it possible?

Always I have to disable protection on MSE, it's very annoying, is there something I can do (except change my browser) to solve this problem?

**Remark:** Maybe this question is better in another Stackexchange site, let me know if it does.

EDIT

I'm still with this problem, so I suppose it's not a https problem. I forgot to mention, I'm using Iceweasel, the equivalent of Firefox in Debian (They are really the same thing according to specialists) I don't know if this information helps, I really want to make MSE works on my browser.

EDIT2
I disable the add-ons on my Firefox and copy the webconsole as the user Robjohn suggested in the comments

[10:06:36.760] Expected 'important' but found 'ie7'.  Expected ';' or '}' to terminate declaration but found 'ie7'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.760] Error in parsing value for 'max-height'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.760] Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.761] Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.762] Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.765] Error in parsing value for 'white-space'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.766] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.766] Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.766] Expected color but found 'top'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.767] Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.768] Unknown property '-moz-outline-style'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.770] Expected color but found 'bottom'.  Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Unknown property 'background-position-x'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Expected media feature name but found '-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Expected media feature name but found '-o-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Expected media feature name but found 'min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.771] Unknown property '-moz-background-size'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:36.772] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/all.css?v=c4e4756d4737:1
[10:06:41.394] Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ https://math.stackexchange.com/:802
[10:06:43.024] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3

Thanks

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You are loading non-secure pages using an `https://` URL. Change the URL to start with `http://` and it should be fine. You may need to change the security settings of your browser.

Comment: Yes it probably is due to the `https://` I tried that in chrome and the page doesn't even open. "Probably not the site you're looking for" in big scary red letters. If I didn't know any better, I'd genuinely be intimidated.

Comment: I have tagged your question ([meta-tag:firefox]), see the [tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/firefox/info). If you find out that your problem is not browser dependent, feel free to remove this tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks!

Comment: @robjohn I'm still with this problem, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 It's not a duplicate, please see my edit

Comment: @Sabyasachi I'm still having problems to load hava symbols.

Comment: @user42912: Look at [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12447/tex-rendering-via-https#comment48797_12448) and try turning on the web console in Firefox. That should display some information that may be useful in debugging the problem. You probably have some security software that needs to be disabled.

Comment: @robjohn please see my edit

Comment: @user42912: do you have cookies turned on? Don't turn on third party cookies, but you do need site cookies turned on.

Comment: @robjohn yes, the third party cookies are allowed. I disabled the add-ons and I marked remember history in preferences and I'm still having problems to see latex symbols.

Comment: Do you have similar problems when visiting [Mathjax.org](http://www.mathjax.org/)?

Comment: @127.0.9.6 I restarted Firefox without https everywhere, now everything is working well, but without this add-on.